# LISTEN query timeout with node-postgres?

Tags: postgresql, node.js, asynchronous

I have an "article" table on a Postgresql 9.1 database and a trigger that notifies a channel on each insert.

I'd like to create a node.js script that catches those inserts and pushes notifications to connected clients using Socket.io. So far I'm using the node-postgres module to LISTEN to the channel but it seems the LISTEN query times out after about 10-15 seconds and stops catching the inserts. I could query a new listen when the timeout happens, but I'm not sure how to properly implement the continuation.

Here's my postgresql notification procedure:

```
CREATE FUNCTION article_insert_notify() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
  NOTIFY "article_watcher";
  RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER article_insert_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON article
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE article_insert_notify();
```

And the node.js code:

```
var pg = require ('pg'),
    pgConnection = "postgres://user:pass@localhost/db"

pg.connect(pgConnection, function(err, client) {
    client.query('LISTEN "article_watcher"');
    client.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log(data.payload);
    });
});
```

How can I ensure a fulltime LISTEN or how could I catch those timeouts to reissue a listen query ? Or maybe a module other than node-postgres offers more appropriate tools to do so ?

Comment: Using [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), complete examples with explanations: [LISTEN / NOTIFY](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise/wiki/Learn-by-Example#listen--notify)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got answer to my issue on the node-postgres repo. To quote Brianc:

> pg.connect is use to create pooled connections. Using a connection
>   pool connection for listen events really isn't supported or a good
>   idea though.
>   [...]
>   To 'listen' a connection by definition must stay open permanently. For
>   a connection to stay open permanently it can never be returned to the
>   connection pool.

The correct way to listen in this case is to use a standalone client:

```
var pg = require ('pg'),
    pgConnectionString = "postgres://user:pass@localhost/db";

var client = new pg.Client(pgConnectionString);
client.connect();
client.query('LISTEN "article_watcher"');
client.on('notification', function(data) {
    console.log(data.payload);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`LISTEN` is supposed to last for the session lifetime or until you do `UNLISTEN`. So, as long as your code is running, notifications should be delivered. Note, that IIRC, postgresql gives no promises to deliver one notification per `NOTIFY` — if you have many inserts it may choose to deliver a single `NOTIFY`. Not sure about 9.1, they introduced `LISTEN` payload, so it may make a bit less sense.

Comment: Then the 15 seconds timeout is a client problem ? Can I solve that with node-postgres or am I just not having the good approach for what I want to do ?

Comment: I'm not really acquainted with node part and I'm not sure I fully understand what happens with pg and this whole environment after the code posted...

Answer (score 0):

A permanent connection in `pg-promise` is

```
db.connect({direct: true})
  .then(...)
  .catch(...);
```