# node-postgres: Not working issuing a NOTIFY job from postgres CLI

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have some code thats works Ok in PHP.
From the postgres CLI I issue a

```
NOTIFY job;
```

The notification is correctly raised by Postgres ( I can see it in the PHP client),
but can't read it in node.

JS:

```
var pg = require('pg');
var conString = "your postgres information";
var client = new pg.Client(conString);

client.connect();
client.query('LISTEN job');
client.on('notification', function(msg) {
    console.log('data');
});
```

I would prefer to keep it simple. Is the only way to make a
procedure in postgres like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262375/listen-query-timeout-with-node-postgres)?

Comment: Ok, the problem was in the conString

var conString = "tcp://user:pass@localhost/db";
I was connected to the generic postgres db, and not the correct one.

Comment: Please post that as an answer and accept it when the timer lets you. I'll upvote if you leave a comment here when you've done so. Thanks for following up.

Comment: I did it, but forgot to comment here :) thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the problem was in the conString parameter.

```
var conString = "tcp://user:pass@localhost/db";
```

Is important to check that you are using the correct database to reach the notification messages.